# How to use my.nuxt.dev instead of my.nuxt.dev:3001 without changing the port?

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js

In my DNS, I have the an URL `my.nuxt.dev` redirecting to `192.168.1.2` where my Nuxt instance is installed. In `nuxt.config.js`, I have configured:

```
  server: {
    port: 3001,
    host: 'my.nuxt.dev'
  },
```

Now, when I want to access the Nuxt website, I have to open `my.nuxt.dev:3001`. What should I change in my configuration to just use `my.nuxt.dev` (without using another port) ?

===

I tried to fix it with Nginx proxy:

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-nuxt.conf`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.nuxt.dev;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:3001";
        }
}
```

But I get an error message in my browser:

> 502 Bad Gateway
> nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Maybe because I also have another Nginx server block (virtual host) on the same port (?):

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-laravel.conf`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.laravel.dev;
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by replacing `127.0.0.1` by `my.nuxt.dev` at `proxy_pass` line.